# How does render() works after returning it in views.py file in django?

Tags: python, django, view

Here is my code from **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basicapp import forms

def form_name_view(request):
    form = forms.FormName()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.FormName(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print("Validation sucess!!")
            print("Name: "+form.cleaned_data['name'])
            print("Email: "+form.cleaned_data['email'])
            print("Text: "+form.cleaned_data['text'])
    return render(request,'basicapp/form_page.html',{'form':form})
```

In my opinion, if statement inside `form_name_view` **should not** work because it is taking data from `form` input to print name,email etc in console. but my doubt is that to fill data inside form there need to load `basicapp/form_page.html` and it is inside return statement.
so after executing return statement how could if statement execute as return statement is end of the function

Comment: The data for the form comes from the POST data: `forms.FormName(request.POST)`. The if statement and print statements happen before the return statement. The form doesn't rely of the template. The `render` requires the template and the form to render the html that is returned to the user.

Comment: but how does form does'nt rely on template,using template we fill data into the form.So,form_page.html should load at first

Comment: The view runs once for a GET request, the template is rendered with an empty form, and displayed in your browser. Then you submit the form from your browser in a POST request. When the view runs a second time for this POST request, it gets the data for the form directly from the POST data - `form = forms.FormName(request.POST)` - it does not use the template.

Comment: Thanks alot! i get it. When i am using get method, if statement  is not working. Thanks once again! One more doubt, why does the function need to run for get and post both,i mean why does it need to run twice both for get and post?

Comment: Once to display the blank form (GET request), then once to process the form (POST request).